# App store submission with Archived Objects

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, appstore-approval, nskeyedarchiver

So, for my project I created a utility app in which I used NSKeyedArchiver to store the data into this archive file.

When I submit to the appstore, does it need to contain the code for how the archive was made or is just the archive fine?

More info:
  I created classes that would parse data and store in archive file

In my project file, I copied the archive from the docs directory of the utility app to my project      folder.

Then I unarchived using NSKeyedUnarchiver.

I just don't know if the app testers would need to see the data parsing/archive creation.

What do you think?

Comment: Just an advice on the side; you should try to get an higher accepting rate: people will start to stop answering your question on SO otherwise...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only submitting `binary` during the submission process to iTunesConnect; App testers don't need to see/won't see the archive data creation: the process will be totally transparent for them.

Comment: Thanks! I just haven't seen this approach used before by someone else online, but it does make sense.